# What questions can OPs delete?

Tags: discussion

I was under the impression that a user can delete their question as long as there is no answer to the question. [This question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/38079/my-mother-stole-my-passport-and-the-police-wont-help) indicates that I have no clue about the question-deletion rules. That Q was deleted by the OP, and there was an answer to the question. So, under what conditions can a question be deleted, and when is a poster forced to accept the consequences of their question?

Comment: Can't see deleted posts here, but check the vote breakdown on the answers. If they are not upvoted/accepted, then OP can still delete the question.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is in https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/260340

> You can't delete your own question if it:
>
> - has an answer with upvotes (even if that answer has a net zero or negative score)
> - has an accepted answer
> - has multiple answers (even if there are no upvotes)
> - has an answer with an awarded bounty